# Unable to catch SoapFault exception. Bad Gateway

Tags: php, soap, exception, try-catch, soap-client

I am unable to catch a SoapFault exception inside my PHP try catch block. my code is also running out of the max_execution_time (of 120 seconds) waiting for response from the server.

I am seeing the message

> **Warning: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Bad Gateway in D:\wamp\www\dev6\application\libraries\Search.php:161  ...**

My code,

```
try {

    $oClient = new SoapClient( $this->CI->config->item('indexing_wsdl_url'),
                                array(
                                    "trace"         => true,
                                    "exceptions"    => true,
                                )
                            );

    $result = $oClient->add(
            array(
                // Application specific parameters goes here
            )
    );// (this is line number 161 as seen in the warning)

} catch (SoapFault $fault) {

    log_message('error', $fault->getMessage());
}
```

I am using Codeigniter 3.0 framework, and this particular code resides inside a library.

What could be the issue here?

Regards

Comment: Are you using namespaces by chance?

Comment: No i am not using namespaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the time out.

The error was caught when I gave more time for the script to execute.